# How can I use multiple GLSurfaceViews on multiple activities in Android

Tags: android, glsurfaceview

I am trying to use multiple activities, each with a GLSurfaceView. Each GLSurfaceView uses a Renderer that calls out to a C++ renderer.

The system works as expected when I start the first activity and when I move to the second.  However, if I then try to go back to the first activity, I get a SEGFAULT from libc from the GL thread of the second activity. The problem appears even with a dummy renderer that does nothing. I feel like I am missing something important...

Renderer

```
public class GL2JNIRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

      public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        return;
      }

      public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        return;
      }

      public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        return;
      }
}
```

GLSurfaceView

```
public class BasicJNIGLView extends GLSurfaceView {
   public BasicJNIGLView(Context context) {
      super(context);
      setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
   }

   public BasicJNIGLView(Context context, AttributeSet attribs) {
      super(context, attribs);
      setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
   }

   @Override
      public void onPause(){
      super.onPause();
   }

   @Override
      public void onResume(){
      super.onResume();
   }

   private Context context_;
}
```

I can reproduce this by using a single activity (from which various extraneous details were removed) that launches a copy of itself:

Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   ...
  private BasicJNIGLView glSurface_;
  private GL2JNIRenderer myRenderer_;

   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      // Load the layout from the XML file.
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      // Hide the layout until the map is initialized (if we show it right away
      // the loading/initialization of the map does not look pretty). The
      // layout will be made visible again in the InitializeLocationTracker
      // function.
      findViewById(android.R.id.content).setVisibility(View.GONE);

      // Set the custom renderer.
      glSurface_ = (BasicJNIGLView) findViewById(R.id.basicJNIGLView1);
      myRenderer_ = new GL2JNIRenderer();
      glSurface_.setRenderer(myRenderer_);
   }

   @Override public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();

      glSurface_.onResume();

      findViewById(android.R.id.content).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }

   @Override
   public void onStop() {
      super.onStop();
   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
   }

   @Override
   public void onPause() {
    glSurface_.onPause();
     super.onPause();
   }


   public void onButton(View view) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Backtrace from LogCat follows.  Thread 20885 is the openGL thread for the second activity.

```
01-29 18:00:47.841: A/libc(20857): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 20885 (Thread-222)
01-29 18:00:47.931: I/DEBUG(17463): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-29 18:00:47.931: I/DEBUG(17463): Build fingerprint: 'generic/google_sdk/generic:4.4/KRT16L/892118:eng/test-keys'
01-29 18:00:47.931: I/DEBUG(17463): Revision: '0'
01-29 18:00:47.951: I/DEBUG(17463): pid: 20857, tid: 20885, name: Thread-222  >>> com.gamma.trafficrouting <<<
01-29 18:00:47.951: I/DEBUG(17463): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
01-29 18:00:48.241: I/DEBUG(17463):     r0 b77c6d38  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
01-29 18:00:48.241: I/DEBUG(17463):     r4 00000000  r5 b6f6d190  r6 00000000  r7 00000000
01-29 18:00:48.251: I/DEBUG(17463):     r8 b77c93c0  r9 00000000  sl 00000000  fp 00000000
01-29 18:00:48.251: I/DEBUG(17463):     ip 00000000  sp a9eb4d10  lr aef68737  pc 00000000  cpsr a0000010
01-29 18:00:48.251: I/DEBUG(17463):     d0  0000008543052000  d1  3ff0000043052000
01-29 18:00:48.251: I/DEBUG(17463):     d2  4301000000000000  d3  4301000000000000
01-29 18:00:48.251: I/DEBUG(17463):     d4  4481e000448b2000  d5  0000012b3f800000
01-29 18:00:48.251: I/DEBUG(17463):     d6  42d8000043958000  d7  3f8000003f800000
01-29 18:00:48.251: I/DEBUG(17463):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
01-29 18:00:48.251: I/DEBUG(17463):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
01-29 18:00:48.251: I/DEBUG(17463):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
01-29 18:00:48.251: I/DEBUG(17463):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
01-29 18:00:48.251: I/DEBUG(17463):     scr 60000010
01-29 18:00:48.261: I/DEBUG(17463): backtrace:
01-29 18:00:48.261: I/DEBUG(17463):     #00  pc 00000000  <unknown>
01-29 18:00:48.261: I/DEBUG(17463):     #01  pc 00007735  /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
01-29 18:00:48.261: I/DEBUG(17463):     #02  pc 0000f059  /system/lib/libEGL.so (eglReleaseThread+44)
01-29 18:00:48.261: I/DEBUG(17463):     #03  pc 0000d538  /system/lib/libc.so
01-29 18:00:48.261: I/DEBUG(17463):     #04  pc 0000ec78  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_exit+80)
01-29 18:00:48.261: I/DEBUG(17463):     #05  pc 0000d1f8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463): stack:
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4cd0  00000000  
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4cd4  a9eb4d44  [stack:20885]
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4cd8  00000000  
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4cdc  b5b0a323  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+346)
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4ce0  b6ee0df0  /system/lib/libbinder.so
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4ce4  b779cc88  [heap]
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4ce8  00000000  
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4cec  ae79afc3  /system/lib/libOpenglSystemCommon.so (HostConnection::get()+6)
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4cf0  b77c93c0  [heap]
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4cf4  00000000  
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4cf8  00000000  
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4cfc  00000000  
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4d00  00000000  
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4d04  00000000  
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4d08  b6f6d190  
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4d0c  aef68715  /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):     #00  a9eb4d10  b6f6b510  /system/lib/libc.so
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          ........  ........
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):     #01  a9eb4d10  b6f6b510  /system/lib/libc.so
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4d14  b6f3111f  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+50)
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4d18  b6f69000  /system/lib/libc.so
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4d1c  b779cc88  [heap]
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4d20  b779cc88  [heap]
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4d24  00000000  
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4d28  b6ed33b1  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::threadDestructor(void*))
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4d2c  b6f2dafd  /system/lib/libc.so (free+12)
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4d30  b779cc50  [heap]
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4d34  b6f6b320  /system/lib/libc.so
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4d38  b6ed33b1  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::threadDestructor(void*))
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4d3c  b6d13de8  /system/lib/libEGL.so
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4d40  b6f6b328  /system/lib/libc.so
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4d44  b6cd702d  /system/lib/libEGL.so (eglReleaseThread)
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4d48  b77c8928  [heap]
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4d4c  b6f6b510  /system/lib/libc.so
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          ........  ........
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):     #02  a9eb4d60  00000019  
01-29 18:00:48.271: I/DEBUG(17463):          a9eb4d64  b6f2d53c  /system/lib/libc.so
```

Comment: Can you show the native crash in your question?  Also, any interesting-looking logcat lines immediately above it.

Comment: Looks like you're crashing when `eglReleaseThread()` is called from the pthread TLS key destructor.  Do you see similar crashes on an actual device?  I don't have full confidence in GLES2 on the emulator.

Comment: It seems that you're right.  It works fine on the device. Thanks!